# ¿Por qué no se guardan todos los datos en el archivo txt? (Tuplas)

Tags: python, txt, tuplas

tengo un programa que registra en una tupla la fecha/hora y el valor medido (obtenido desde arduino). El código en python es:

```
import sys, time, serial
from datetime import datetime

time.sleep(3)             # Generar un retardo 3ms
numPoints = 10            # Cant de datos

dataList = []
dateTimeList = []

with serial.Serial('COM6', 9600) as ser:
    
    def getValues():
        ser.write(b'g')
        arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii','ignore')
        arduinoData_2 = arduinoData.strip(',\r\n')
        
        ahora = datetime.now()
        fecha = ahora.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")

        return fecha, arduinoData_2
    
    
    for i in range(0,numPoints):
        data = getValues()


    registro = open("prueba5-comserial.txt", "w")
    header = "DateTime, Valores"
    registro.write(header + "\n")

    for i in range(0, numPoints):
        registro.write(', '.join(data) + '\n')

    registro.close()
```

El problema es que no se está guardando en el archivo .txt todos los datos que se miden, si no que solamente el último medido.

Ejemplo: Lo que debería guardarse en el archivo txt es:

```
DateTime, Valores
25-09-2022 23:42:55.886216, 1
25-09-2022 23:42:55.982254, 2
25-09-2022 23:42:56.078378, 3
25-09-2022 23:42:56.176200, 4
25-09-2022 23:42:56.287813, 5
25-09-2022 23:42:56.382972, 6
25-09-2022 23:42:56.478772, 7
25-09-2022 23:42:56.574957, 8
25-09-2022 23:42:56.687147, 9
25-09-2022 23:42:56.783169, 10
```

Lo que se está guardando actualmente en el txt:

```
DateTime, Valores
25-09-2022 23:42:56.783169, 10
25-09-2022 23:42:56.783169, 10
25-09-2022 23:42:56.783169, 10
25-09-2022 23:42:56.783169, 10
25-09-2022 23:42:56.783169, 10
25-09-2022 23:42:56.783169, 10
25-09-2022 23:42:56.783169, 10
25-09-2022 23:42:56.783169, 10
25-09-2022 23:42:56.783169, 10
25-09-2022 23:42:56.783169, 10
```

Quisiera saber en dónde se encuentra mi error y de qué forma corregirlo. Cualquier recomendación y ayuda es bienvenida.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Estas sobreescribiendo `data` en cada iteración del `for` por eso solo se guarda el último valor de la iteración. Podrías combinar los dos `for` que tienes en uno solo (En el segundo) para escribir los datos cuando los obtienes. Otra opción sería eliminar el primer `for` y en el segundo, en lugar de hacer `registro.write(', '.join(data) + '\n')` cambiarlo por `registro.write(', '.join(getValues()) + '\n')`

Comment: @HeytalePazguato gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haz la lectura y grabación dentro del mismo `for`. Quda así:

```
registro = open("prueba5-comserial.txt", "w")
header = "DateTime, Valores"
registro.write(header + "\n")

for i in range(0, numPoints):
    data = getValues()
    registro.write(', '.join(data) + '\n')

registro.close()
```

Comment: además debe cambiar el valor de range (1,numPoints+1) y agregar i en la escritura si lo que busca es que guarde desde 1 a 10 junto con los datos